# Python - Check the URL return

Tags: python, web-scraping

im writing a small to script to web scraping  url and check if is what i need.
If the URL return json add a YES column on my url's list.

```
import webbrowser
webbrowser.open('https://mvneves.com.br/wp-json/wc/v3')
```

But my problem is - when the url is ok - dont return a json file.

https://mvneves.com.br/wp-json/wc/v3
This is the result i want

How can i write to my script - if return this, add yes to the column?

Thank u!

Comment: You need to use the urllib library, not webbrowser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use a library like [requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) more.

---

Update:

```
>>> from requests import get
>>> result = get('https://mvneves.com.br/wp-json/wc/v3')
>>> result.json()
{'namespace': 'wc/v3', 'routes': {'/wc/v3': {'namespace': 'wc/v3', 'methods': ['GET'], 'endpoints': [{'methods': ['GET'], 'args': {'namespace': {'required': False, 'defaul...
```